# ¿Cómo puedo forzar la descarga de una imagen con Javascript al cargar la página?

Tags: javascript, html

El siguiente código me permite descargar una imagen al cargar la página. Ajunto [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/azw08zt5/) para que vean el ejemplo. Sin embargo, si añado una imagen cualquiera en el href, la imagen no se descarga, solo se muestra. Lo que debería hacer es que al cargar la página, la imagen se descargue.

```js
var a = document.createElement('a');
a.href = "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcQL6mIpFVuGIvfidrEHwUe5hyd_cnF1A3K4AA&usqp=CAU";
a.download = "miimagen.png";
document.body.appendChild(a);
a.click();
document.body.removeChild(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

Como mínimo debes tener creada la estructura básica de `html` para que `javascript` pueda ejecutar el evento `appendChild` en el `body`, de lo contrario, te saldrá un error en la consola similar a este:

> (index):5 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null
> at (index):5

Adicionalmente, la imagen debe estar dentro de tu proyecto.

En el siguiente ejemplo, asumo que la imagen está en el mismo directorio que el archivo `html`, si está en otro directorio, debes cambiar la ruta. Haz la prueba en tu pagina o en un servidor local como `xampp`. No agrego el código en un snippet ya que no va a funcionar.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var a = document.createElement('a');
        a.href = "porsche.jpg";
        a.download = "porsche.jpg";
        document.body.appendChild(a);
        a.click();
        document.body.removeChild(a);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Podrías hacerlo así:

- Usamos `data:application/octet-stream` para indicarle al navegador que debe descargar el archivo.
- Usamos `encodeURIComponent` para codificar la URL al archivo a ser descargado.

#### Ejemplo:

```js
var imgURL = 'https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcQL6mIpFVuGIvfidrEHwUe5hyd_cnF1A3K4AA&usqp=CAU';
var a = document.createElement('a');
a.href = 'data:application/octet-stream,' + encodeURIComponent(imgURL);
a.download = "miimagen.png";
document.body.appendChild(a);
a.click();
document.body.removeChild(a);
```

**PD**: En el fragmento de ejemplo no se descarga la imagen por las políticas de `sandbox` que posee el `iframe`

Comment: Creo que los navegadores tampoco te permiten simular el clic sin previa acción del usuario.

Comment: @Triby, se puede y normalmente debería funcionar, aunque algunas veces el navegador bloquea el _"popup"_ por razones de seguridad. Esto es lo que hacen comúnmente los sitios de descarga de archivos, te muestran un mensaje pidiendo que esperes unos segundos hasta que empiece la descarga.

Comment: No lo he probado así, porque normalmente lo hago con un _META REFRESH_ a un script para realizar la descarga, pero se trata de conceptos diferentes.

Comment: Y si quisieras mostrar una pantalla de agradecimiento, ¿como lo harías?

Comment: No es después, es antes... Pantalla de agradecimiento que incluye _META REFRESH_ y, como se trata de una descarga, el navegador no cambia de página.

Comment: Entiendo. Estoy acostumbrado a ver el mensaje de "agradecimiento" después de iniciada la descarga.